# NodeJS JSON response required through key value mapping

Tags: node.js, key-value

Getting some events and their data if event is not available the we have to set zero value.
Getting data like below,

```
  "result" : {
      "2" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "3" : {
            "buckets" : [
              
              {
                "key" : "updated",
                "doc_count" : 5
              },
              {
                "key" : "created",
                "doc_count" : 3
              },
              {
                "key" : "deleted",
                "doc_count" : 3
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "3" : {
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "created",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "deleted",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          
          "3" : {
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "created",
                "doc_count" : 46
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    }
```

desired response:
{"chartData":{"dataset":[{"label":"created","data":[3,1,46,]},{"label":"updated","data":[5,0,0]},{"label":"deleted","data":[3,1,0]}]}}

how to set label and data dynamically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize empty items first, then re-structure and map data to your expected structure.

```js
const input = {
      "2" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "3" : {
            "buckets" : [
              
              {
                "key" : "updated",
                "doc_count" : 5
              },
              {
                "key" : "created",
                "doc_count" : 3
              },
              {
                "key" : "deleted",
                "doc_count" : 3
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "3" : {
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "created",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "deleted",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          
          "3" : {
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "created",
                "doc_count" : 46
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}

const decoratedInputs = input['2']['buckets']
  .map(item => {
    const rawItems = item['3']['buckets']
    const formattedItems = []
    const created = rawItems.find(item => item.key === 'created')
    if (!created) {
      // init created item
      formattedItems.push({key: 'created', doc_count: 0})
    } else {
      formattedItems.push(created)
    }
    
    const deleted = rawItems.find(item => item.key === 'deleted')
    if (!deleted) {
      // init deleted item
      formattedItems.push({key: 'deleted', doc_count: 0})
    } else {
      formattedItems.push(deleted)
    }
    
    const updated = rawItems.find(item => item.key === 'updated')
    if (!updated) {
      // init updated item
      formattedItems.push({key: 'updated', doc_count: 0})
    } else {
      formattedItems.push(updated)
    }
    
    return formattedItems
  })

const result = {
  chartData: {
    dataset: [
      {
        label: 'created',
        data: decoratedInputs.map(item => {
          const created = item.find(item => item.key === 'created')
          return created.doc_count
        })
      },
      {
        label: 'updated',
        data: decoratedInputs.map(item => {
          const updated = item.find(item => item.key === 'updated')
          return updated.doc_count
        })
      },
      {
        label: 'deleted',
        data: decoratedInputs.map(item => {
          const deleted = item.find(item => item.key === 'deleted')
          return deleted.doc_count
        })
      }
    ]
  }
}

 console.log(result)
```